# Why isn't my mod_rewrite working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'l make this short and sweet:

I want to type in this:
`http://pachonk.com/alex/admin/user/`

And get this:
`http://pachonk.com/alex/admin/index.php?page=users`

I'm trying to use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /alex
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?page=$1
```

With other variations, but this isn't working. What's wrong?

Comment: Where is the rule located and are there other rules?

Comment: @JonLin Added more details.

Comment: So these rules are in an htaccess file in the `/alex` directory? And there are no other mod_rewrite rules?

Comment: For now there aren't...

Comment: Assuming .htaccess file is in `/alex` directory, maybe the options are not correct. Try this instead: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

Comment: @Pachonk I just tried this in my test environment and it rewrites properly to `/alex/admin/index.php`. Maybe the problem lies in `user` vs `users`.

Comment: @faa That worked! Why though...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure mod_rewrite and .htaccess are enabled in `httpd.conf`. Then put this slightly modified code in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/alex/.htaccess` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /alex/

RewriteRule ^admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ admin/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Read about Multiviews here: http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/archives/2005/04/beware-of-apaches-multiviews btw did this answer work for you or not?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mark accepted! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you.